# Play! Framework Wait for response

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework-2.0

to the first I would like to stress that I am newbie to Play! Framework.
What I'm supposed to do is convert Poker game, written previously to work in console, to work with GUI  based on Play Framework.
My problem is, that until now I had things like:

```
System.out.println("What's your name");
name = input.nextLine(); //input was initialized as: new Scanner(System.in)
```

It means, that user is asked about something, then we wait for response and when an answer is provided something more happens (like sending the name to server).

In order to provide such a functionality I've written class:

```
public class Printer {
    public static void print(String str) {
        if (Player.isGUIModeOn()) {

        }
        else {
            ConsolePrinter.println(str);
        }
    }

    public static String prompt(String str) {
        String out = "";
        if (Player.isGUIModeOn()) {

        }
        else {
            out = ConsolePrinter.prompt(str);
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

but I have no foggiest idea how to implement this part related to prompting user to provide some data, both how to change part of displayed website asynchronously (print) and wait for it's (site) response.
My question is what techinques should I use and/or read about to achieve such functionality. Examples and pieces of code are always welcome.

I have to use Play! Framework v2

Comment: You do realize that a web application is NOTHING like a regular console application? Its not a simple code translation; you need to completely redesign the application to fit with how web applications work.